# Scroll UICollectionViewCell Swift 3 acording to the selected UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, xib

I created a storyboard with a toolbar. Also, I created a UICollectionViewCell/XIB and imported it inside the storyboard. I added many UITextFields inside the UICollectionViewCell. When
I select the UITextFields which are in the bottom of the screen, the screen doesn’t scroll to show it. Could you give me some tip about how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Is your cell height dynamic or fixed? If it is fixed, you can have a trick like, once the textfield becomes active, detect the selected cell with some `delegate` or `didSelectItemAt`, then multiply the indexPath.row of the cell with cellHeight property, then set `contentOffset` of `collectionView` to that value like:

```
// cellHeight property is something you should have declared somewhere.
collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: cellHeight * indexPath.row), animated: true)
```

If the solution above does not work, then get the keyboardHeight programmatically, or set a value that would be good enough for you to scroll up, for example I will set it to 200, then get the currentOffset, add your value to currentOffset's y value in `didSelectItemAt` method, (just for reference):

```
let currentOffSet = collectionView.contentOffset
let newOffset = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: currentOffSet.y + 200.0)
collectionView.setContentOffset(newOffset, animated: true)
```

This might be a better solution depending on your application. But remember to set offSet back to original value, maybe in `resignFirstResponder` kind of method with your textField, so there wont be a weird behaviour each time user taps a cell.

Comment: hi emrepun. how could I know if the cell height is fixed or dynamic?

Comment: You should know that actually, how did you design your cells? Did you give fix heights on storyboard, or in sizeForItemAt method programmatically? Or is it dynamic and calculates automatically?

Comment: I added a toolbar on the screen. Below, I added the collectionview on the full screen. The collectionview contains an imageview and three textfields one below the other. There are some textviews too